# SSLError when Adding add_done_callback method to BigQuery query

Tags: ssl, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I have an application running in GCP Cloud Run that is sampling and flattening some (unions of) tables using a CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE statement and then executing a function on that new table.  I obviously need to wait for the query to complete in order to execute the function, but I would like to continue the process on other sets of tables.  Naturally, I tried using the add_done_callback method of the google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJob class, but it seems to be having some issues with polling.

The pertinent part of my code is this:

```
query = create_query(dataset_id, target_dataset_id)
callable = Callable(some_args) # some args will be passed into a function that callback executes
bq_read_client.query(query).add_done_callback(callable.callback)
```

and it is intermittently giving the below errors

```
Exception in thread Thread-6 (_blocking_poll):
...

ssl.SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)
...
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigquery.googleapis.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/bigquery/v2/projects/<project>/queries/<query_id>?maxResults=0&location=US&prettyPrint=false 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))

...
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1000)
```

Is there a way to configure the polling in the add_done_callback method to be less frequent or do increase the number of max retries, or is there some entirely different way to fix this?

Comment: Try enabling **CPU always allocated** as a debug step. Disable after testing is complete as there is a cost. More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation). This test will see if the CPU being idled after a request returns is affecting your software design (async completion).

Comment: @JohnHanley it actually solved my problem... its very interesting. Is the real issue here that with CPU idled the application cannot properly poll BigQuery?

Comment: When Cloud Run receives an HTTP request, it spins up a container to handle the request. Once the request returns an HTTP response, the CPU is idled. If your container is then waiting for a response from another service while the CPU is idled, bad things happen as there are no CPU cycles to handle the async response. That means you need the CPU to be always allocated or you must wait for the async response before your container completes the HTTP response.

Comment: This behavior can appear indeterminate. For example, if the container receives another HTTP request, the CPU is allocated and the waiting async code will now have CPU cycles. That can make these types of problems hard to debug. In summary, do not complete the HTTP request until all processing has been completed (no background threads).

Comment: Is it okay to just always let the CPU be allocated? This is kind of a long running process and I want to acknowledge it quickly (ASAP) and just run everything after the response.

Comment: It is a supported feature and appears to solve your issue. There is a price increase so double-check that item if it matters.